# How to burn coordinate point of polyline to the pixel value while converting it from vector to raster

Tags: qgis, proximity, rasterization

I am trying to plot a proximity raster for secondary roads in a particular area. What I have is a set of polyline representing the roads. Now, I want to create a proximity raster based on the polyline. 
First of all I need to create a raster from the polyline which I am perfectly able to. Now, how can I insert burn in value of the pixel to be it's lat and long coordinate?

Comment: I want the proximity raster to display the actual distance in meters/km however qgis always seem to produce a scaled down version. How can I map the scaled version of the distance to actual distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a proximity raster using the [Proximity (raster distance)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html#proximity-raster-distance) processing tool directly from your rasterized polyline. No need to burn coordinates as new rasters...

However, if your coordinates are lon, lat then your data is in a geographic (lon, lat) CRS and the horizontal units are degrees which are *not* a good choice for distance measurements.

I suggest reprojecting your polyline to a projected coordinate reference system (CRS) with horizontal units in metres before rasterizing.